# Find the relevant elements in an XML Reader c#

Tags: c#, xml

I basically have an xml reader and each Node is a camera with certain elements Uid, name etc. I'm trying to find a way to be able to type in a  name and find its relevant uid.

This is my code so far:

```
 using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"\\IPADDRESS\Customers\customers\GRACE-SVR1\XmlConfig\EXAMPLE.XML"))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "CAMERA"))
                {
                    if (reader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("name"));
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("uid"));

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

This displays the information but i'm just wondering how to go about typing in a name and it searches the xml for the relevant uid

Comment: It's not clear what kind of problem you have. You don't know how to read value from console? This code is not related to *typing in  name and searching for relevant uid*. This code is simply writing name and uid attributes of all camera elements

Comment: Wait, so it's getting the information you want, but you don't know how to take input to filter out different nodes?

Comment: its retrieving the information but only displaying it, i want to be able to type in a name and it give me the relevant id element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are searching for this.

```
var name = Console.ReadLine();

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"\\IPADDRESS\Customers\customers\GRACE-SVR1\XmlConfig\EXAMPLE.XML"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "CAMERA"))
        {
            if (reader.HasAttributes && reader.GetAttribute("name") == name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute("uid"));

            }
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XDocument.Load` to load the XML and get all the elements of type 'Camera' using a LINQ query